# Wrong array values returning from a function

Tags: c, arrays

I am making this program in which my main function calls a function which returns an array after the calculation. I checked already that calculation is right inside the local function. But when I return that array to 'main' function then I only can print the correct value one time and it prints wrong value all other times.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int* getJoinedPipes(int input1_size, int* input1,int* output_size){
  int i,j,temp;
  int op1[input1_size-1];
  *output_size = input1_size - 1;
  for(i=0; i<input1_size; i++){
    for(j=i+1; j<input1_size; j++){
      if(input1[i] > input1[j]){
        temp     = input1[i];
        input1[i] = input1[j];
        input1[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }

  op1[0]=input1[0] + input1[1];
  for(i=1;i<input1_size-1;i++){
    op1[i] = op1[i-1]+input1[i+1];
  }
  //printf("%d\n",op1[2]);

  return op1; 
}

int main() {
  int output_size;
  int* output;

  int ip1_size = 0;
  int ip1_i;
  scanf("%d\n", &ip1_size);
  int ip1[ip1_size];
  for(ip1_i = 0; ip1_i < ip1_size; ip1_i++) {
    int ip1_item;
    scanf("%d", &ip1_item);

    ip1[ip1_i] = ip1_item;
  }
  output = getJoinedPipes(ip1_size,ip1,&output_size);
  printf("a==%d\n",output[0]);
  printf("a==%d\n",output[0]);
  printf("a==%d\n",output[0]);
  int output_i;
  for(output_i=0; output_i < output_size; output_i++) {
    printf("%d\n", output[output_i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output should be

```
5
9
15
```

But in the console, it's showing the following (after dry run). [image: See the image]

```
a==5    
a==1943372821    
a==1943372821    
1943372821    
17    
6356632
```

You can see first time its giving correct value (5) and later for same print its giving garbage values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope) and many other  similar questions

Comment: Edited the answer with console values

Comment: Never post pictures of text when you can post the text.

Comment: Alright ! And I am returning values not address

Comment: `op1` __is__ an address, not a value. It's the address of the first element of the local array `op1`. `op1` ceases to exist once you exit from the function. Read the answer with the most upvotes of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: @MichaelWalz to be pedantic `op1` is an array. When you `return op1;` it returns a pointer to the first element - `op1` "decays" into a pointer in many contexts, including this one.

Comment: Keep in mind that you **cannot** return an array from a function, nor can you pass an array as an argument. You can, as you try to do here, return or pass a pointer to an array's initial element. (The length of the array has to be specified in some other way, since the pointer doesn't carry that information.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning pointer to a local variable object whose lifetime has ended yet when you are trying to get its values -> horrible mistake and undefined behaviour.

If you want to return an array from function, allocate it dynamically via `malloc`, and dont forget to `free` it after you are done with that array. You should also check return value of `malloc` if you got memory you asked for.

**Correct**

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int* getJoinedPipes(int input1_size, int* input1,int* output_size){
int i,j,temp;
int * op1 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (input1_size-1));
*output_size = input1_size - 1;
for(i=0; i<input1_size; i++){
    for(j=i+1; j<input1_size; j++){
        if(input1[i] > input1[j]){
            temp     = input1[i];
            input1[i] = input1[j];
            input1[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}

op1[0]=input1[0] + input1[1];
for(i=1;i<input1_size-1;i++){
    op1[i] = op1[i-1]+input1[i+1];
}
//printf("%d\n",op1[2]);

return op1;
}

int main() {
int output_size;
int* output;

int ip1_size = 0;
int ip1_i;
scanf("%d\n", &ip1_size);
int ip1[ip1_size];
for(ip1_i = 0; ip1_i < ip1_size; ip1_i++) {
    int ip1_item;
    scanf("%d", &ip1_item);

    ip1[ip1_i] = ip1_item;
}
output = getJoinedPipes(ip1_size,ip1,&output_size);
printf("a==%d\n",output[0]);
printf("a==%d\n",output[0]);
printf("a==%d\n",output[0]);
int output_i;
for(output_i=0; output_i < output_size; output_i++) {

    printf("%d\n", output[output_i]);

}

free(output);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Returning pointer to local variable (degraded from array) is different than returning (the value of) a local variable. The latter is how your answer could be misread. The first is the problem. I recommend to rephrase.

Comment: The problem isn't that the array object is out of scope; that just refers to the region in which its name is visible. The problem is that the returned pointer points to an object whose *lifetime* has ended. If `op1` where defined as `static`, it would be valid to return a pointer to it (or to its initial element), even though it would still be out of scope.

Comment: Thank you for correction @KeithThompson, i have written that variable is _out of scope_ i thought its same as _which lifetime has ended_. Am i wrong? Thank you for kind explanation.

Comment: Recommend `int *op1 = malloc(sizeof *op1 * (input1_size - 1));` and insure `input1_size > 2`.

Comment: @FilipKočica: *Scope* is the region of program text over which an identifier is visible. *Lifetime*, or *storage duration*, is the span of time during execution in which an object exists. See section 6.2 of the C standard; [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) is the latest publicly available draft.

Answer (score 5):

`op1` is an automatic array. You cannot return it and use it outside its scope.

`op1` exists only within `getJoinedPipes`, if you return it, the result is **Undefined Behaviour**.

To fix it you can either:

- pass `op1` as a parameter to `getJoinedPiped`
- allocate `op1` on the heap dynamically. You you do that, you can safely return `op1` but you have to remember to `free` it when you don't need it.

Comment: This is why is called Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @Swarnveer Undefined behavior means anything can happen, including "appearing to work"

Answer (score -2):

You should check your indentation... apart from that, I guess the problem could arise because the array you output in your function is created on the function stack. So what you get as an output array is a reference on the stack of your joinedPipes-function. Try to pass your array as an argument to the function and not create it as a return value.

Hope that does the trick...